# Thunderbird shortcut for moving message to folder

Tags: linux, thunderbird

How can I add *move message to folder X* shortcuts?

I know about pressing <kbd>a</kbd> for moving a message into the *archive* folder but I need more than that one since I often need to move messages into two other folders. (I'd like to be able to use a shortcut to move to folder X and another shortcut to move to folder Y.)

Comment: I use [QuickFolders extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/thunderbird/addon/quickfolders-tabbed-folders/), which has good support for easily moving messages into folders and it does allow to create keyboard shortcut. I didn't check whether it would help with what you are trying to do exactly, but it's quite likely.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the [Quick Folder Move](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/quick-folder-move/?src=dp-dl-othersby) add-on for something similar.

With <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> you can open a dialogue and type in the folder name that the selected mail(s) should be moved to.